# Cover the methods in inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

import java.util.AbstractList;

public class ItemSet extends AbstractList {

```
private Item[] arr;
private ItemClass itemClass;

public ItemSet(Item item) {
arr = new Item[1];
arr[0] = item;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.util.AbstractList#add(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean add(Item e) {
boolean isNotAdded = true;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (e.getRule().compareTo(arr[i].getRule())) {
    if (e.getDot() == arr[i].getDot()) {
        isNotAdded = false;
        break;
    }
    }
}
if (isNotAdded) {
    Item[] oldArr = arr;
    arr = new Item[oldArr.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(oldArr, 0, arr, 0, oldArr.length);
    arr[oldArr.length] = e;
}
return isNotAdded;
}

@Override
public Item get(int index) {
return arr[index];
}

@Override
public int size() {
return arr.length;
}

// SETTER

/**
 * @param itemClass
 *            the itemClass to set
 */
public void setItemClass(ItemClass itemClass) {
this.itemClass = itemClass;
}

//

// GETTER

/**
 * @return the itemClass
 */
public ItemClass getItemClass() {
return itemClass;
}
//
```

}

How to cover for instance removes methods?
How do not use an own list implementation?

Comment: What do you mean by "cover"? Please clarify your question.

Comment: He wants not to implement the other methods of the interface, I think.

Comment: Shouldn't an `ItemSet` extend `AbstractSet` instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to inherit remove(), then don't extend `AbstractList`, instead delegate the methods you want to an `ArrayList`.

Like this (and for the love of god don't comment your setters and getters)

```
    public class ItemSet {
    private final ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private ItemClass itemClass;

    public ItemSet(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public boolean add(Item e) {
        boolean isNotAdded = true;
        for (Item item : items)
            if (e.getRule().compareTo(item.getRule()))
                if (e.getDot() == item.getDot()) {
                    isNotAdded = false;
                    break;
                }
        // why are you adding here?
        if (isNotAdded)
            items.add(e);
        return isNotAdded;
    }

    public Item get(int index) {
        return items.get(index);
    }

    public int size() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void setItemClass(ItemClass itemClass) {
        this.itemClass = itemClass;
    }

    public ItemClass getItemClass() {
        return itemClass;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is it a good style of the java programming? I think this is a burden to the call stack, isn' t it?

Comment: Calling add() in ArrayList runs in constant time.  In your implementation System.arraycopy() runs in O(n) time.  These things make a much bigger difference than possibly increasing the call stack which may be optimized away(?).  A thinner public interface is better design as well.

Comment: Calling add() in ArrayList runs in constant time. In your implementation System.arraycopy() runs in O(n) time. I know this, I had to write in the fast way, so I don't care about this. But thanks. A thinner public interface is better design as well. What do you mean?

Comment: A thin interface (less exposed methods) reduces [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to implement the other methods in the interface, simply define them to throw an exception:

```
public bool remove(Object o)
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

If you don't want to even do that, you should inherit from a class, not implement an interface.